# Parent Activity Tool bar is hiding in child fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-framelayout

Please find the Activity xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@color/white"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10ssp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_menu"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_15sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_menu"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            />


                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            style="@style/mediumTextInput"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/text"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp" />

                        <com.suke.widget.SwitchButton
                            android:id="@+id/sb_private"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            app:sb_background="@color/light3"
                            app:sb_checked="false"
                            app:sb_checked_color="@color/colorPrimary"
                            app:sb_checkline_color="@color/colorPrimary"
                            app:sb_show_indicator="false"
                            app:sb_uncheck_color="@color/light3"
                            app:sb_uncheckcircle_color="@color/white"

                            />


                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fl_main_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
       </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:visibility="visible"
    />
```

and this is my child fragment xml file

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <FrameLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".fragment.MapFragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:id="@+id/iv_my_location"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_my_location_light4_with_background"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I am displaying map in child fragments and I need to show the Toolbar in the map at top position,(Toolbar background should be transparent to map)

***But , child fragment is hiding the toolbar, how to bring this Toolbar inside the map*** ? Toolbar is common to all fragments.

My requirement is , "Map should occupy whole page it should not below to the tool bar , that's y I didn't give the layout below in Framelayout

Comment: Have you tried _toolBar.bringToFront()_?

Comment: @Piyush , I forgot this small point , Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add/Replace the fragment inside the Framelayout with id fl_main_container

Also add

android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"

to the framelayout i mentioned, that will basically make the entire portion below the toolbar free to be occupied with the fragment, currently it is occuptying the whole screen thus covering the toolbar

EDIT:

Since the map should occupy the whole screen, skip the layout below part.... instead use the wonderful android way of painting views and simply put the toolbar below the framelayout in the xml.... It should paint the toolbar above the framelayout

Comment: Question is , Child Fragment hiding the tool bar of parent

Comment: yea and the answer should help

Comment: My requirement is , "Map should occupy whole page it should not below to the tool bar , that's y I didn't give the layout below in Framelayout

Comment: alright, my bad at misunderstanding your need... try the edit